Remove specifc exif data properties from photo on iOS
Is there a way to remove specific EXIF fields, such as "Make" or "Model" from photos on iOS?
It seems, I can change/remove date or location (ref), but I would like to remove the fields related to the camera that was used to take the photo.
Edit: It would be great to do this without installing an additional app.

You can create a Shortcut to convert a photo into one without metadata (link to shortcut).

There are also multiple EXIF editors in the App Store.
